# Unexpected Token import on react-router with webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I've seen tons of questions on this already, and I've went through basically all of them but still didn't fix my issue. I am trying to add a simple "react-router" module to my reactjs app. I got my code from [here](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist)

From reading answers on similar posts, I know that node.js doesn't support es6 module syntax yet. I am trying to use Babel with es2015 to solve this problem.

**/src/app/index.js**

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Link } from 'react-router';
```

I've read from other answers that I need a .babelrc file when I use babel:

**/.babelrc**

```
{
  "preset": ['es2015', 'react']
}
```

This is my webpack and package.json files:

**/webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app/'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

};

**/package.json**

```
{
   "name": "react-playlist",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "A simple react to-do list",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "npm run build",
       "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --
       inline --hot --port 1234 --history-api-fallback"
   },
   "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist.git"
   },
   "keywords": [
       "react"
   ],
   "author": "The Net Ninja",
   "license": "MIT",
   "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist/issues"
   },
   "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist#readme",
   "dependencies": {
       "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
       "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
       "babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
       "react": "^15.3.2",
       "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
       "react-router": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^1.13.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
     }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Link } from 'react-router';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What command gives you that error?

Comment: Running "node index.js" in /src/app

Comment: That's client code; you shouldn't run it with Node.  You need to run your Webpack server.

Comment: Right, I get it now. I forgot to run "npm start" which allows me to start up the Webpack server.

Comment: I'm getting an error though when I run "npm start": Invalid: '{ presets: [{option: value}] }'. I am guessing something is wrong with my babelrc

Comment: I think the reason is because I typed "preset", it should be "presets" *facepalm*. Calling "npm start" works now, I can see the website hosted on localhost:1234

Comment: Everything works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On a side note, since you have `.babelrc` file added, you don't need the presets set for babel in your webpack config.